# ¿cómo remover la llamada a una función cuando se dispare un evento?

Tags: javascript, function

Llevo tiempo tratando de solucionar este problema y no puedo. He preguntado en foros pero tampoco pueden. Espero que hoy sea el dia. Parece sencillo pero no lo es. Se trata de eliminar la llamada de una funcion cuando se ejecute otra funcion. La idea es que una funcion me imprima en la pantalla la palabra "uno" cuando le haga click al boton numero uno, y que me imprima "dos" cuando le haga click al boton numero dos, PERO, PERO, eliminando la llamada a la funcion anterior (esto para que no aparezca su contenido cuando se ejecute la otra funcion). Cabe mencionar que no quiero remover elementos o contenido, porque en mi codigo original, dentro de las funciones UNO y DOS hay muchiiiisimo codigo, muchisimos elementos y animaciones y funciones, y no me sirve remover elementos uno por uno (ademas que habrian funciones que no se podria remover)..Lo que yo quiero es desactivar la funcion por completo, que todo su contenido deje de ejecutarse y que en la pantalla no me imprima nada de esa funcion, como si no existiera (que esto pase cuando se ejecute otra funcion. Y que se vuelva a activar cuando le de click a su boton, y que se desactive la otra, asi sucesivamente). Mejor dicho: quiero remover la llamada a una funcion cuando ocurra un evento. Este es mi codigo base:

```js
function UNO () {
      $( 'body' ).prepend( 'uno' )
    }

function DOS () {
  $( 'body' ).prepend( 'dos' )
}

$( 'button:first' ).click( function (  ) {
  UNO()
} )

$( 'button:last' ).click( function (  ) {
  DOS()
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>uno</button>
<button>dos</button>
```

Comment: Siento decirte que a pesar de tus esfuerzos explicando el escenario sigo sin entender qué es lo que quieres hacer: ¿Qué quiere decir *eliminando la llamada a la funcion anterior*?

Comment: Por cierto, te he creado un scriptlet en la pregunta para que puedas explicar lo que quieres más fácilmente

Comment: Hola. Cuando le hago click al BOTON 1 me llama a la funcion UNO, y cuando le hago click al BOTON 2 me llama a la funcion DOS, pero yo no quiero que ambas funciones coexistan. Quiero que cuando una funcion se ejecute, la otra desaparezca, que no se ejecute su script. La solucion pienso que es eliminar la llamada a una funcion cuando se ejecute otra. Por ejemplo: UNO(); DELETE DOS() .......(obviamente esto no funciona, pero es solo un ejemplo para que me comprendas)

Comment: Lo siento no se que es eso de "scriptlet"

Comment: El scriptlet es lo que ves en tu pregunta... puedes ejecutar el código que has puesto

Comment: Entonces quieres que si pulso en "uno" (ejecutando la función `UNO()`), el botón dos deje de llamar a la función `DOS`, ¿es eso?

Comment: si...eso. Que si pulso en el boton 1 llame a la funcion 1 pero que deje de ejecutar la funcion dos, y viceverza.

Comment: Pero eso es lo que ya hay: el botón uno llama a UNO y el botón dos a DOS.

Comment: Hay que entender que, al menos en tu código, usas funciones sincrónicas. Se entra a tu primera función, ejecutando instrucción por instrucción de forma secuencial y saliendo de la misma, todo eso cada vez que se haga un llamado a alguna de tus funciones. Con tu estructura de código, la función dos no se va a ejecutar hasta que finalice el función uno. Teniendo en cuenta tu código de ejemplo no sabemos si dentro de estas funciones existe código que precise de callbacks o promesas, como para continuar con las demás instrucciones mientras se espera la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes intentar usar: [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
function UNO() {
  $('body').prepend('uno')
}

function DOS() {
  $('body').prepend('dos')
}

$('button:first').click(function() {
  UNO()
})

$('button:last').click(function() {
  $('button:first').off('click');
  DOS()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>uno</button>
<button>dos</button>
```